# UrlRewrite to not redirect for certain files

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

I am using Tuckeys UrlRewrite filter for getting clean urls on my java application. I redirect all the requests to a certain resource to a spring request dispatcher. Here is my original rule

```
<rule>
   <from>(.*)$</from>
   <to>$1.htm</to>
</rule>
```

Problem is that accessing .js, .css files also seem to be redirecting. I want to know how to write a rule with a negation for any extensions. So the rule should match all single words (like login, logout) and not match for words with extensions (like login.jsp, image.jpg, sc.js ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [<condition>](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/#condition) element where you disallow certain paths to be rewritten:

```
<rule>
   <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">\.[a-z]+$</condition>
   <from>(.*)$</from>
   <to>$1.htm</to>
</rule>
```